# Grouping and displaying a collection of events in a table with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm after some WPF advice; I have a list of objects that define a time, event type and description like so:

```
public class AnEvent
{
    public EventType EventType { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display the collection of items like this:

```
-------------------------------------
|   Time    |   Type1   |   Type3   |
-------------------------------------
|   12:00   |  Event1   |           |
-------------------------------------
|   12:01   |  Event2   |  Event4   |
|           |  Event3   |           |
-------------------------------------
|   12:05   |           |  Event5   |
-------------------------------------
```

- Multiple events can occur at the same time, they should be displayed in the same 'cell'
- The table should only show columns for event types that are present in the collection, as the event types that are present can vary.
- There will be 15 - 20 EventTypes, but there will only be 3 or 4 present in a given collection.

What's the best way to display this data in WPF?

I've considered using a Grid, but I'm not sure how to

- Dynamically generate the columns
- Dynamically generate the rows
- Assign a row and column to the object (I'd use a datatemplate to define how to render a ViewModel based on the event)

I've also considered preprocessing the list of events to generate a collection of events by time, and then a collection of events by type within that, and then using several ItemsControls to display the different levels.

What are my other options?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the amount of types always going to be the same, or are they going to be dynamic?

Comment: The EventType is an enumeration that will not change, but the collection of items will not always contain all entries defined by EventType.

Comment: Okay.. working on a sol. right now

Comment: once the collection is loaded initially, are the events going to change?

Comment: Nope. They'll only change when the entire collection is reloaded, but will be static after that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you write a simple VM as is

```
public class EventLogByTimeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AnEvent> Type1Collection { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AnEvent> Type3Collection { get; set; }
}
```

And create a factory to which you would provide a list of AnEvent and which would output a list of VM

```
public interface IEventLogByTimeVMFactory
{
    IList<EventLogByTimeViewModel> GenerateVM(IList<AnEvent>);
}
```

You could surely use the `GroupBy` method from Linq extensions inside your factory implementation for an easier process.

Then in your high level view model (the one you bind to DataContext), expose and implement the collection of EventLogByTimeViewModel as is

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IEventLogByTimeVMFactory _factory;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        EventLogs = new ObservableCollection<EventLogByTimeViewModel>();
        _factory = new MyFactoryImplementation();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EventLogByTimeViewModel> EventLogs { get; set; }

    public void LoadData(IList<EventEventLogByTimeViewModel> eventLogs)
    {
        var vms = _factory.GenerateVM(eventLogs);

        EventLogs.Clear();

        foreache(vm in vms)
        {
            EventLogs.Add(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

The mecanism by which you would call the LoadData method is up to you.

Finally in your UI, I encourage you to use the `DataGrid` control, bind the `EventLogs` property to its `ItemsSource` and finally implement `DataTemplate` for both Type1 and Type3 columns that would display the `EventType` collections inside a `ItemsControl`.

Comment: I considered something like this, but if Type2 isn't present in the collection, I don't want it to be displayed. Updated my example to try and make that clearer.

Comment: Then just don't include it in the grouping view model. I updated.

Comment: The collection is loaded dynamically so will have a different set of events in it each time, and thus a different set of EventTypes. In one case it may have EventTypes 1 and 2, in another only 2 and 3.